# Delete unused files

Tags: .net, visual-studio

My project contains many JavaScript files.
many of them are not needed.
and there is no reference from them on my project. 
is there any way or tool for removing them from solution automatically on Visual studio 2010?

Comment: how come they are in the solution but not in any project?

Comment: Is there a really huge number of scripts that you need tool for it?

Comment: Not really. i am just looking of better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any automatic way, if they are not used, they should not be added to the project in first place, if its legacy project and many people worked on it over the time leaving stale file, you can find all such stale files by using search feature and if its a Web Site project simple delete them from storage and Web site will automatically drop them, if its a Web application project them you have to open .csproj or .vbproj files and remove all references to such files from these files, usually something like ... will be there, then you can delete those files from storage. Finally going forward if its a Web site project you .....tag in web.config for such files so you know exactly what is being used also you can avoid have include tags on individual Pages and Controls.